# Detecting Touch in a Div Box ? Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, touch

Say I have setup a basic div like this :

```
<div id='signatureBox'></div>
```

I then want to register whenever the box is clicked on / touched in any area. I am trying without success :

```
//Register signature callback
var signature = document.getElementById("signatureBox");
signature.onclick() = function () {
alert('signature JavaScript triggered');
        }
```

Can anyone help ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've put in the parentheses which are unneeded for the onclick in javascript.
Correct working code is here

```
var signature = document.getElementById("signatureBox");
signature.onclick = function () {
    alert('signature JavaScript triggered');
}
```

Working fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/7m9EK/1/

Difference between HTML and javascript `onclick` to be found here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp